# User Control Property c#

Tags: c#, winforms, custom-controls

I want to create list property of `UserControl` to add and select item in design time. What is the best way to do this? here is relevant code:

```
 public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    List<string> _item = new List<string>();

   [Browsable(true)]
    public List<string> item
    {
        set
        {              
            _item = value;              
        }
        get
        {
            return _item;
        }
    }
```

I added items to List but I can't select it in design time.

**Edit:** I want to create a property of user control Like this:
[image]

Comment: In my approach I get another editor ;) like multiline string editor... interesting/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to inform the designer how to edit the property:

```
[Editor("System.Windows.Forms.Design.ListControlStringCollectionEditor, System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a", typeof(UITypeEditor))]
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
[MergableProperty(false)]
public List<string> Items
{
    get
    {
        ...
```

The `Editor` attribute points to the type that contains the editor the designer can present to the end user.

The `DesignerSerializationVisibility` attribute is required for the code generation part, otherwise the entered items don't end up in the generated `InitializeComponent()` method.

The `MergableProperty` attribute hides the property as soon as multiple controls are selected.